# Include all singleValueExtendedProperties for an event in the API response?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm very new to the Microsoft Graph API, however, I am developing a calendar "booking" system (in NodeJS) that creates events in a shared calendar using the Microsoft Graph API. When I create the events, I include around 9 singleValueExtendedProperties. Previously I was inputting these values in the body but it made it difficult to parse them later on when/if needed as it's saved as html.

I have an event update form and function which I am trying to implement. Basically, I am (trying) to grab an event based on a single value extended property I set, and then take all of the rest of the properties associated with the event and save them as variables in my code (which I then prefill in a form).

I'm having two issues:

1. When I use the API without filters

```
const events = await client.api(`/users/${sharedMailbox}/calendars/${calendarId}/events`)

                                   .select('id,subject,body,singleValueExtendedProperties')

                                   .expand('singleValueExtendedProperties')

                                   .get();
```

I don't get any matching results - is it not possible to not specify a filter so it uses all singleValueExtendedProperties?

2. When I do specify a filter and get a response/match, the json response I get doesn't include singleValueExtendedProperties in it anywhere. It includes everything else except it.
   How can I get all of an event's singleValueExtendedProperties in a response from a Graph API call? If also possible, I'd prefer to even be able to get all events, and in the response for all of the events, include all singleValueExtendedProperties for each.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange (or the Graph) will only return the SingleValueExtendedProperties that you specify in the Get Request. So to one property you would use

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq 'String 0x0037')
```

for multiple property just bracket and use an or statement eg

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(id eq 'String 0x0037') or (id eq 'Binary 0x300B') or (id eq 'Integer 0x0E07'))
```